# Setup DNS for external ssh access to 2 different hosts on same public ip

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, port-forwarding

I have 2 Raspberry Pi's running and want to be able to access them externally. I have DynDNS running to link my public IP to mydomain.com. The goal is to be able to use host1.mydomain.com to ssh into host1 and host2.mydomain.com to ssh into host2.

I was able to almost realize this by using port forwarding in my router settings but then I always needed to specify the port when connecting via ssh. Is it possible to realize this within the DNS setup?

Comment: SSH does not care about DNS, you need to use different ports if you only have one public IP. You might want try to get public IPv6 on the hosts instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set up that using a jumphost which has direct access to both systems. Or, if one system has access to another, you can use it as jump host. But your access to that other system will depend on the first.

Comment: Okay, thank you both for the explanation. Will probably follow the setup with jumphost or simply add the ports manually when using SSH.

If you'd post this as an answewr, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted :)